# Открыть второе окно (форму) в функции по таймеру в Java

Tags: java, javafx

Подскажите, как можно открыть вторую форму через определенный промежуток времени из функции?

Форму создаю таким образом:

```
public class  NewEntry {
public void display(int timerSek, String torrents)
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Rectangle desktopBounds = ge.getMaximumWindowBounds();

    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.setTitle("Новые материалы за последние "+ timerSek + " секунд");
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setWidth(400);
    window.setHeight(300);
    window.setX(desktopBounds.x + desktopBounds.width - 400);
    window.setY(desktopBounds.y + desktopBounds.height - 300);
    TextArea newText = new TextArea(torrents);
    newText.setEditable(false);

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().add(newText);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}
}
```

Пытаюсь вызывать так

```
class TimerFreerutor extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        XmlParser.xmlMethod(s -> journal.setText(s.replace(",","\n")), s1 -> last10.appendText(s1.replace(",","\n")));
        NewEntry newEntry = new NewEntry();
        newEntry.display(30,last10.getText());
    }
}
```

В методе `start` класса `Main` делаю так:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerFreerutor(), 6000, 6000);
```

Но оно не срабатывает, выкидывает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:241)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
at sample.NewEntry.display(NewEntry.java:18)
at sample.Main$TimerFreerutor.run(Main.java:63)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Если вызывать форму по нажатию на кнопку или, например, просто прописав в методе `start`, то все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся графика должна обрабатываться только в FX потоке, о чем и сообщает вам ошибка.
Что бы попасть в нужный поток оберните создание формы в `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: спасибо, помогло